# How to record data that causes runtime exception in spring batch reader

Tags: spring-batch

I need to capture the runtime exception in reader and skip them, so I use skipPolicy to do that as below. Also there is a requirement to record which data causes the runtime exception. I have some conversion logic in reader, but ItemReadListener does not have the access to item info. I am not sure where/how to access such data info.

Should I move the the conversion logic from reader to processor, then implement ItemProcessListener to record the error item? In this case, should the step1 method be udpated below? Thanks in advance!

```
@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .reader(reader1())
        .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(runtimeExceptionSkipper())
    .processor(processor1())
    .writer(writer1())
    .build();
}


@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Job> reader1() {

    return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Job>()
                    .dataSource(dataSourceConfig.dataSource())
                    .name("reader1")
                    .sql(Constants.QUERY_JOB_SQL)
                    .rowMapper(new JobRowMapper())
                    .build();

}

public class JobRowMapper implements RowMapper<Job> {


    public Job mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {

        Job jobSchedule = new Job();
        String timeZone = rs.getString(Constants.COLUMN1);

        LocalDateTime localStart = 
        rs.getTimestamp(Constants.COLUMN2).toLocalDateTime();

        ZonedDateTime utcStart = ZonedDateTime.of(localStart, 
        ZoneId.of("GMT"));

        ZonedDateTime zonedStart = 
        utcStart.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(timeZone));

        job.setEffectDate(zonedStart.toLocalDate());

        return job;
    }
}

@Bean
public Step updatedStep1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("updatedStep1")
        .reader(reader1())
    .processor(processor1())
        .faultTolerant().skipPolicy(runtimeExceptionSkipper())
        .listener(itemProcessListener())
    .writer(writer1())
    .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do here is obtain the information from the `Exception`.  The reason we don't provide it via a listener is that there is no "item" to pass on.  Given that each source of the data is unique, we cannot provide a generic way to provide what that data was.  However, in most cases, we do our best to provide as much information about what caused the error in the `Exception`.  For example, the `FlatFileParseException` does include the `String` we were trying to parse as well as the line number where the error occurred.  If you provide us with more information about the specific `ItemReader` you are using, we may be able to provide further guidance.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I add the JdbcCursorItemReader in the code above. The runtime exception occurs in the rowmapper class where timezone is parsed due to the bad data. How can I record the bad data in such scenario? @Michael